# jQuery UI Tabs - no create event

Tags: jquery-ui, events

I'm using jQuery UI 1.10.1, but checked this in 1.10.3 as well. Although the [documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#event-create) states the create event is *"Triggered when the tabs are created"*, I can find no such trigger in the code and neither does it work. "tabscreate" event isn't fired either.

Am I missing something or did they just forget to update the documentation and [changelog](http://jqueryui.com/changelog/1.10.0/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been using the TABS widget for a couple of years and have never had any issues. Are you sure it's the [`create`](http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#event-create) event you want to use or [`activate`](http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#event-activate)?

Comment: Color me purple, I created a fiddle with only the tabs code, and it seems to work (sorry, that should've been the first thing to do):
http://jsfiddle.net/arminrosu/Gww7x/

I suppose it must be an error on my part somewhere else. Marked your response as my answer, thanks for taking the time to respond.

Yes, I need the `create` event, since `activate` get's called on every tab activation, I need an event for when it's ready.